# How to execute a value after subtracting from two textbox instantly in a third textbox in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a ASP.NET page, code written in C#. Actually i am preparing an Fee collection system. I have used MS SQL Server. There are 4 text box
1) Amount Paid
2) Discount Amount
3) Balance Amount
4) Total Amount

Now Total Amount is the net amount which is to be paid by a Student. Balance amount is the subtraction of "net amount to be paid - Amount paid". Discount Amount is the amount if any discount is offered . Paid amount is the amount which student is depositing.

Now i want to write a code when i enter a value into Amount Paid it should automatically subtract and show the balance amount in the balance field immediately. Example:- If the balance amount is 3500 and if i enter 500 into Amount Paid field instantly it should subtract and show 3000 in the balance field.

All the data are coming from MS SQL Server database and has to be stored in that same database.

How it can be done please write the coding for me. I am trying from last 12 days but unable to execute.

I have attached the screen shot of that page structure for better understanding.

Comment: Please show the code you've written. We're not a code writing service. Please don't ask us to write the code for you. We will help you fix your code though.

Comment: Thanks @David. could u pls suggest some code

Comment: AbhishekPradhan -- the suggestion by @Enigmativity is a suggestion that you should follow -- post some code showing what you have already tried.  It is a very good idea to *always* do this when posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: Don't see attachment. Please post code.